# Multiline regex replacement in sed/vi

Tags: regex, replace, newline

I need to replace this statement in a named.conf with regex

```
masters {
        10.11.2.1;
        10.11.2.2;
};
```

All my approaches with sed/vi do not work

```
%s/masters.*\}\;//g
```

does not match. Also tried with /s \s etc to match the newline.

Comment: By replace do you mean remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vim, you can [force a pattern to match across newlines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines) with `\_`, for example:

```
%s/masters {\_[^}]*};//g
```

It's important to replace `.*` with something more conservative like `[^}]*` if you prefix with `\_`, because `*` is greedy, so `\_.*` will try to match everything to the end of the document.

Comment: Thanks. Never would come up with with this myself. RegEx is the new rocket science!